# Rxjava2 combine multiple operations

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, rx-android

For example if i have 3 functions

```
Completable requestLogin()

Single hasProjects()

Completable createDefaultProject()
```

How i can combine them in single request

requestLogin() `>` onComplete `>` hasProjects() `>` onSuccess `>` if(!hasProjets) `>` createDefaultProject()

It is possible? and what happen in case of errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's one of the reasons you'd use Rx. One possibility could be:

```
requestLogin()
   .andThen(
         hasProjects()
            .filter(value -> !value)
            .flatMapCompletable(value -> createDefaultProject()))
   .subscribe(() ->{}, throwable -> {
         // All errors will end up here
     });
```

We request the login and once it completes we check if there are projects. If the are not, the `filter` will not terminate the stream which creates the default project. If there are projects, then no default project is created.

If along the way there is any error, the `onError` method will be called and you can handle the errors there.